# Counting values in a column separately and return different lines for each count [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have the following data in a table:

TableX

```
ID   COMPANY_ID  Procedure
-----------------------
1       1         TST1 
2       2         TST1
3       3         CHK1 
4       4         CHK2
5       5         TST3
6       6         TST3
```

I want to do a count of the number of companies in SQL that contain each procedure, where a procedure can be represented by multiple different codes (e.g. TST1 and TST3 represent the same procedure).

```
Procedure   Count  
-----------------------
TST*          4           
CHK*          2
```

Would it be possible to do this using only one query? Notice how all of the procedures that start with TST are counted together even though they end in either 1 or 3. This leads to a total count of 4, whereas the count for CHK procedures is 2.

Comment: what Database r u talking to?

Comment: This is a SQL query.

Comment: Thank you, I was asking the database! which database? e.g. Mssql can have different string functions from Mysql

Comment: It would be my a custom database that belongs to the organization so you wouldn't be able to access it?

Comment: are you serious?? I am asking what database are you working with, you just need to tell "oracle", "postgres", "MySQL".... something like that, I am not attempting to access your database

Comment: Yes of course - it is SQL Server (https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/sql-differences). Sorry! Never been asked that.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
select substring(procedure,1,3) as pro, count(company_id) from your_table
group by substring(procedure, 1,3);
```

Comment: I think this does the trick. Would it be okay to omit substring(procedure,1,3) from the select clause? Can I add a where filter like so that only picks out certain procedures?

select count(company_id) as count 
from your_table
where your_table.procedure IN ('TST1', 'TST3') OR your_table.procedure IN ('CHK1')
group by substring(procedure, 1,3);

Comment: @EdwardChau You can think about it, if there is no the `substr(...) pro` in select, the result would be numbers only `3, 4,5, 6` can you tell the `4` is for which procedure? Moreover, can't you test it on your own? do you have a sql-client tool?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Like` Operator in `CASE` Expression to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
Company_ID INT ,
[Procedure] VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1,'TST1')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2,'TST1')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3,'CHK1')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(4,'CHK2')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(5,'TST3')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(6,'TST3')
```

Main Query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [PROCEDURE] LIKE 'TST%'THEN'TST*'
            WHEN [PROCEDURE] LIKE 'CHK%'THEN'CHK*' END AS [PROCEDURE]
        ,COUNT(COMPANY_ID) AS [COUNT] FROM @T
GROUP BY CASE WHEN [PROCEDURE] LIKE 'TST%'THEN 'TST*'
              WHEN [PROCEDURE] LIKE 'CHK%'THEN 'CHK*' END
```